# How to create a table in KAFKA using Confluent KSQLDB with a console / command line / cli?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to create a table in KAFKA using Confluent's KSQLDB.  I have easily use the UX provided by Confluent but I am trying to automate this process and hence *I need a command line scipting capability to execute this task*.

I have been able to use Confluent's KSQLDB REST interface to execute curl for simple commands ("LIST STREAMS") but more complicated statements, such as creating a table, seem to be unavailable, or there are no examples available to clone/use.

Does anyone have a command line script or a know of a console command to create a KSQLDB table (in Confluent's version of Kafka)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`/ksql` endpoint](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/ksql-endpoint/). For example:

```sh
curl -s -X "POST" "http://localhost:8088/ksql" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.ksql.v1+json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d '{"ksql":"CREATE TABLE MOVEMENTS (PERSON VARCHAR KEY, LOCATION VARCHAR) WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='\''JSON'\'', KAFKA_TOPIC='\''movements'\'');"}'
```